# Add HTML tags to selected text

Tags: html

Sounds simple but I really can't find the answer. I would like to be able to select text and add a tag without typing opening/closing tags manually, because it's a waste of time.

```
<p> selected text </p>
<ul>
    <li> selected text </li>
    <li> selected text </li>
    ...
```

What comes to my mind are workarounds like Notepad++ (find & replace) or Autohotkey scripts (copy, add tags and paste) + StrokesPlus mouse gestures.
Is there any editor where I could do it quickly with a shortcut? I'm new to HTML and I just want to find the most efficient solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Many editors support this feature and if not, there are mostly extensions you can add for html language support.

In [sublime-text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) for example if you write `div` then hit the **tab**-key you get `<div></div>` with the cursor positioned within the div scope, which makes life way easier.

One other solution that you might find interesting is writing with the template engine [Jade](http://jadelang.net/). Just have a look its pretty straight forward.

Comment: I've found a shortcut in Sublime. Select your text and press alt+shift+w, it will enclose the selection in a tag, <p> by default, but you can edit < > and < / > simultaneously to whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

With notepad++
if you want to change some lines as list ( < li > )

- Select your text and press CTRL+H (to replace)
- write in the first input (find what): **(.*)**
- and in the second input (replace with):
  **< li >\1< /li >**
- check in the options: "In selection" and "regular expression"
- Finaly click on replace all

Answer (score 0):

You can use [emmet](https://emmet.io) with the editors that emmet supports, to create a tag you only need to type the word that you want to create and press Tab.

I love [brakets](http://brackets.io) editor; if you´re editing html code it has a live mode to view in real time the changes in your document.